# Delete items in Outlook by 'Type' or 'Message Class'

Tags: vba, outlook

I want to delete meeting notifications.

Emails are not getting sorted by 'type' or 'message class'.

```
Dim olSearchOlFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim mailItem As Object

Set mailItem = olSearchOlFolder.items
olSearchOlFolder.items.Sort "[Message Class]", True

For Each mailItem In olSearchOlFolder.items

    Select Case olSearchOlFolder.Name
    Case "Inbox", "Sent Items"
        Select Case olItemMeetingResponse.Class
        Case olMeetingResponsePositive, olMeetingResponseNegative
            olItemMeetingResponse.Delete
        End Select
    End select

next mailItem
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not loop through all items in the folder, let the store provider do the job - call Items.Restrict with a query on the `MessageClass` property

```
set restrictedItems = olSearchOlFolder.items.Restrict(" @SQL=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x001A001F"" LIKE 'IPM.Schedule.Meeting.%' ")
```

Comment: Streblechenko, Thank you for this ,helps a lot. i tried your advise at first im getting error list separator or ), after i made the changes and im getthing error Condition is not valid:

`Set restrictedItems = olSearchOlFolder.Items.Restrict(" @SQL=" & "https://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x001A001F" & "like '%IPM.Schedule.Meeting.%' ")`

Comment: I also getting `"Cannot parse condition error at  https://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag...`

Comment: The DASL name needs to be doable quoted - see the updated answer above.

Comment: placed the quote and it throws `condition is not valid